# Java - Make List Size Dynamic

Tags: java, arrays, list, dynamic, arraylist

I need to make the size of a list fixed dynamic but dynamic based on the parameters of its initiation.

I am trying the following -

```
int countOptions = countOptions(s_sqlContext, s_organisationId);
String responseListSize = "\"0\"";
String addResponseTuple = ",\"0\"";

for (int i = 1; i < countOptions; i++) {
    responseListSize = responseListSize.concat(addResponseTuple);
}

List<String> ret = Arrays.asList(new String[] { responseListSize });
```

`countOptions` returns an integer that may be 10 for one person or 3 for another. This obviously does not work because it is setting `ret` as a single index List of `"0","0","0","0"` (if countOptions is 4), when I need each `"0"` to have its own index.

I hope this all makes sense, and I really hope it is possible.

Comment: Would it not make more sense to put length constraints around an `ArrayList` instead?

Comment: @ydaetskcoR Would this be something as simple as .size(countOptions) - am I really being this stupid? - monday morning - I am a learner as you may have gathered, only graduated last academic [=

Comment: ^^ idiocy justification

Comment: @ydaetskcoR so size() does not wok with a List<String> any ideas?

Comment: @Phish I assure you that size() works with List<String>, I note that you have only given the list one (concatenated) string in the code above.

Comment: @Caleryn This is what I am doing wrong too! so the list the way I have done it will look like "0","0","0","0" at the first index however what I need is each "0" to be in its own index -

Comment: @Caleryn so List<String> ret = Arrays.asList(new String[] { "0","0","0","0" }); would work however I need the number of "0"'s to be dynamic - I am sorry if I did not make this clear! "the quality of your education equals the quality of your questions" - right

Comment: Thank you for all your comments, solution below plus a couple amendments) have sorted

Comment: @Phish Yes which is why I would not use `Arrays.asList()` at all in this situation, I would do exactly what is being done in the accepted answer, add directly to a new list in your loop, if you actually need the concatenation of zeros for something else, build that later, from the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `ArrayList` instead of String concatenation.

```
List<String> responseListSize = new ArrayList<String>(countOptions);

for(int i = 0; i < countOptions; i++){
    responseListSize.add( addResponseTuple );
}
```